# Python program; parses weather.com for weather; unwanted text is printed

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a program that uses `beautifulsoup` to parse the **weather.com** site and prints the weather. When parsing for the location to be printed, an unwanted word is printed:

Today in Burnaby, British Columbia *Weather*, the  weather outside is Partly Cloudy, at 10°

the **'Weather'** after British Columbia is unwanted. How do I scrape only parts of a text from a class?

***Pertinent code:***

```
current_temperature = soup.find(class_="CurrentConditions--tempValue--3KcTQ").text
current_state = soup.find(class_="CurrentConditions--phraseValue--2xXSr").text
current_location = soup.find(class_="CurrentConditions--location--1Ayv3").text

string = "\nToday in " + current_location + ", the  weather outside is " + current_state + ", at " + current_temperature + "\n"
print(string)
```

***Full output:***

> Today in Burnaby, British Columbia Weather, the  weather outside is
> Partly Cloudy, at 10°

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Can you share the url link for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

If this is a common occurrence, you can try a brute force approach:

```
current_location = soup.find(class_="CurrentConditions--location--1Ayv3").text
current_location = current_location[:current_location.find(" Weather")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = string.replace('Weather ','')
print(x)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it would be good if you provide some explanation on how your code works.

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way is to replace the string entirely with a "".

```
string.replace(" Weather", "")
```

Remember to add a space before Weather, since you don't need the space.